# Swiftui navigationview and tabview give grey header

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, tabview, swiftui-navigationlink

[image]

I have a two-tabbed tab view and in the second tab there are different pages being displayed. There is a navigationview and navigationlink within some of the pages. The navigation bar has a weird grey background that I can’t make go away. Any ideas how to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had a .padding around the view for the second tab, so everything within that view was padded, which introduced this. Removing that solved the issue.